# I can't understand some find_text function in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I started read book about Tkinter

(Tkinter GUI Application Development Blueprints)

and when I began to make my text editor with the help of this book I don't really understand one part.

There is a feature than can help you find words in the text.

```
def find_text(event=None):
search_toplevel = Toplevel(root)
search_toplevel.title('Find Text')
search_toplevel.transient(root)
search_toplevel.resizable(False, False)
Label(search_toplevel, text="Find All:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')
search_entry_widget = Entry(
    search_toplevel, width=25)
search_entry_widget.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=2, sticky='we')
search_entry_widget.focus_set()
ignore_case_value = IntVar()
Checkbutton(search_toplevel, text='Ignore Case', variable=ignore_case_value).grid(
    row=1, column=1, sticky='e', padx=2, pady=2)
Button(search_toplevel, text="Find All", underline=0,
       command=lambda: search_output(
           search_entry_widget.get(), ignore_case_value.get(),
           content_text, search_toplevel, search_entry_widget)
       ).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='e' + 'w', padx=2, pady=2)
```

Lines where we create a button really hard for me. I found out that lambda-function is just like normal function but created in other way, but other stufffff is really hard.Can you please explain me what this code is actually do? (button code)

full code:

https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Tkinter-GUI-Application-Development-Blueprints-Second-Edition/blob/master/Chapter%2002/2.05.py

Comment: But i really want to understand code inside lambda :(

Comment: A lambda is an anonymous function meaning it does not have a name that you can call. The lambda is executing another function called `search_output()`. The `search_output()` function takes 5 positional arguments and the lambada is passing 5 arguments. Based of the arguments submitted to the `search_output()` function it will highlight all the matches by using the tag options. That said Stack Overflow is not here to teach you what the code is doing but to help you understand an error you got with your own code attempts.

Comment: Judging by the github link I and you confusion I think you should work a smaller project. I can also say that the github code wont work as it is missing several imports. You can do `from tkinter import *` to fix this for the github code though. Try some youtube tutorials instead of a book. The youtube tutorials are a better visual and they do a good job of explaining the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will help you to see it written out as a normal function. This code would work just as well:

```
def find_clicked():
    search_output(
        search_entry_widget.get(), ignore_case_value.get(),
        content_text, search_toplevel, search_entry_widget)

Button(search_toplevel, text="Find All", underline=0,
       command=find_clicked).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='e' + 'w', padx=2, pady=2)
```

The only thing lambda is good for is confusing people by stuffing things onto a single line. I recommend you avoid lambda if at all possible.